# AND logic in excel or python for trimming a number

Tags: python, excel

I have an 8 digit number `12345678` and I want to `AND` it with `0000ffff` to get the last 4 digits of the number.

Is there a way to do this in excel or Python? Thanks!

Comment: Why not split last 4 digits?

Comment: ANDing decimal number with hex will not return last 4 decimal digits (except cases when number is less than `9999`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in python the binary `AND` is just

```
12345678 & 0xffff
```

But that'll get you the **last 32 bits** of the number.

If you want the **last four digits**, you can just do this:

```
12345678 % 10000
```

The remainder of dividing by 10000 will give you the last four digits in base 10. You can use [`MOD`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9B6CD169-B6EE-406A-A97B-EDF2A9DC24F3) to do that in Excel.